How to find min of $abc$ providing that $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}: a,b,c \geq 1$ and $a + b + c = 34?$
How to find min of $abc$ providing that $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}: a,b,c \geq 1$ and $a + b + c = 34?$
I know by intuition (and by trials of some values) that two of the numbers must be $1$ and the other must be $32$, but I've been struggling to show that this is the case. I hope someone could provide some help! Thank you very much!

Hint It's equivalent to find the minimum of $$g(b,c)=(34-b-c)bc$$ on $[1,+\infty [^2\cap {(b,c)\mid b+c\leq 33}$

@Surb Sorry but does it require multivariable calculus? I'm not familiar with it yet. However, I'm familiar with single-variable calculus. Please let me know! If you're aware of another approach, I'd love to hear it too!

To optimize $g$ on the boundary of the triangle $[1,\infty [^2\cap{(b,c)\mid b+c\leq 33}$ no need multivariable calculs (single-variable calculs only is required), but in the interior of the triangle you'll indeed need multivariable calculus...

@Surb Thanks! Thb, I'm unable to proceed with your current guidance. Could you please be a bit more detailed? Thank you very much!

Let $a = 1 + x, b = 1 + y, c = 1 + z$ where $x, y, z \ge 0$. We have $x + y + z = 31$. We have $abc = xyz + xy + yz + zx + x + y + z + 1 = xyz + xy + yz + zx +32 \ge 32$.

@RiverLi Very nice proof! Thank you very much!

@ten_to_tenth You are welcome.
